# Rotate or change a font awesome when li is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following `ul li` setup and when I click on an `li` the submenu opens. I also have a font awesome caret next to that `li` and I want to rotate the caret 180degrees or change the icon with the `fas fa-caret-up` icon each time I click to open a submenu. Any ideas on how to do this?

```js
$( 'li.submenu a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next().toggle();
  return false;
});
```

```css
ul.ul_submenu, ul.ul_submenu_2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li class="submenu" id="atag">
        <a href="#">Apparel & Accessories <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
        <ul class="ul_submenu">
            <li class="submenu">
                <a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                <ul class="ul_submenu">
                    <li class="submenu">
                        <a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
                        <ul class="ul_submenu">
                            <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get the  tag, and [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to change the caret direction, note that I used array of classes in `.toggleClass()`, I will leave it to you to change the arrow direction, but for me I would have `caret-left` for closed, and `caret-down` for opened, here is working snippet:

```js
$( 'li.submenu a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next().toggle();
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass(['fa-caret-down', 'fa-caret-left']);
  return false;
});
```

```css
ul.ul_submenu, ul.ul_submenu_2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
    <ul class="ul_submenu">
      <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
        <ul class="ul_submenu">
          <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
            <ul class="ul_submenu">
              <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ROOT... I tried your code and for some reason the icon is not changing even though it appears to work just fine here. I'm placing the code inside a rails app if that make any difference.

Comment: it shouldn't make different if its the same HTML structure, try to re-produce it here and I will fix it.

Comment: I know... I'm using the same exact code you provided and it doesn't work at all. It's not even giving me an error inside the console.. weird!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need a toggleClass and some styling on the `i` class. You can change the icon directly with JS, changing the class of the `i`

```js
   $( 'li.submenu a[href="#"]').click(
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            $(this).next().toggle();
            return false;
        });
```

```css
 ul.ul_submenu, ul.ul_submenu_2{
    display:none;
  }
#atag a i {
    transition: all .3s;
}
#atag a.open i {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="submenu" id="atag"><a href="#">Apparel & Accessories <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
    <ul class="ul_submenu">
      <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Clothing <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
        <ul class="ul_submenu">
          <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Men <i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="color: grey;"></i></a>
            <ul class="ul_submenu">
              <li class="submenu">blabla</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @yomisimie... I did not downvote. I tried your code and for some reason the icon is not changing even though it appears to work just fine here. I'm placing the code inside a rails app if that make any difference.

Comment: Someone else downvoted, but doesn't matter.
I don't know much about rails, but the code should work fine. Basically you need to toggleClass on element when clicking on it. 
And in css you need to rotate the icon when you have the class. Does it give any error at least?

Comment: Nope, I'm getting nothing inside the console.